How to gather >100k news article URLs for data analysis using selenium chromedriver and google?
I have to collect text data from internet news articles from approx 2017 to 2024 from around 5 websites. That's tens/hundreds of thousands of articles. I have a way of scraping some of those URLs directly from the news websites but some of them only allow to repeatedly load 25 more links to news articles on the same webpage, which eventually crashes the web browser that I'm using to crawl through the website. I can use Google Search to find one URL at a time but that's still hundreds of thousands of Google searches, which Google eventually stops. I've had a particular problem with the website https://ct24.ceskatelevize.cz/. Is there any way to get the list of URLs?
I. As I mentioned, first I tried going to the news website and scraping the URLs and the dates of publication from the list of articles using selenium chromedriver. That worked for some websites but others only allow to load older articles on the same webpage, so if I wanted to get to a 2017 article, I would have to load thousands of article links on a single webpage, which would eventually crash the website (not to mention that the news website would eventually cut me off due to the amount of requests, and it takes a progressively longer to load each new set of articles). I can't just stop, reload the webpage, and then continue from where I left off since reloading the webpage would put me back to the newest set of articles.
II. The articles have IDs which I can use to sort of find the URLs. Example: the article URL sort of looks like this "ct24.ceskatelevize.cz/article/category/title-of-an-article-id". I can predict the id but I don't know the article title and the category. I can use a simple Google search like this "site:ct24.ceskatelevize.cz/article id" to find the article URL. The problem is that Google doesn't really like when I do tens of thousands of searches like that and it often tries to verify if I'm a bot, which stops me. I have no idea how to scale this method so that I can get a few hundred thousand URLs.

Read the following solution based on your question!
Note: this answer contains different methods to reach your goals
First:
Based on your question I think you want to gather 100k+ news articles from 2017-2024, if you have a specific news website to target then you can use the Wayback archive machine which will work better than Google search! I have some open-source tools to do this, here is the list of tools that are written in golang & python :
1. gau (getallurls) by Corben Leo:


Written in golang
GitHub repo: https://github.com/lc/gau
Installation: go install github.com/lc/gau/v2/cmd/gau@latest
Help: ./gau -h

2. waybackurls by tomnomnom:

Written in golang
GitHub repo: https://github.com/tomnomnom/waybackurls
Installation: go install github.com/tomnomnom/waybackurls@latest
Help: ./waybackurls -h

3. get-wayback-machine by jfilter:


GitHub repo: https://github.com/jfilter/get-wayback-machine
Written in python
Installation: pip install get_wayback_machine

Second:
I saw you're struggling with this web app https://ct24.ceskatelevize.cz/. well, to reduce the time and requests you can use this script to reach your goal! here are the details:
Your target news web app has an API endpoint called /api/queuedArticles?queueId=17&page=1&pageSize=100, every time you click to see more or load more buttons than your target apps request this endpoint to fetch the news article, you can get 80k+ news article link by running this script, I added a comment on the script for better understanding.
import requests
from datetime import datetime
from requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions import InsecureRequestWarning

requests.packages.urllib3.disable_warnings(InsecureRequestWarning) #disable warning

article_url = set()
def getData(content): #gathering data from json response
    for i in content['data']['articles']:
        article_id = i['article']['id']
        slug = i['article']['slug']
        path = i['article']['mainSection']['path']
        date = datetime.utcfromtimestamp(i['article']['publication']['datePublished']).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
        url = "https://ct24.ceskatelevize.cz/clanek" #article endpoint to append list of links

        pri = f"Article-URL: {url}/{path}/{slug}-{article_id}, Date:[{date}]"
        article_url.add(pri)
   
def gatherArtcle():
    for i in range(1,1061):
        try:
            data = f"https://ct24.ceskatelevize.cz/api/queuedArticles?queueId=17&page={i}&pageSize=100" #API endpoint with limit of 100 result per page. has 1061 page- from 2017 to 2024 news articles
            session = requests.Session()
            req = session.get(data,verify=False)
            response = req.json()
            getData(response)
        except Exception:
            pass
            
gatherArtcle()
for i in sorted(article_url): #sorting value for unique result to avoid possible duplicate.
    print(i)

If you have any doubts about this answer or facing any errors, feel free to reply with a comment.
